# Custom Craft CMS plug-in template changes issue

Tags: craftcms

Somebody has developed a custom plug-in for a project of mine.
I now want to change some templates from this plug-in and no matter what changes I make to these templates, nothing changes! I don’t understand why. I’ve cleaned caches several times and the cache tag is not used. It’s my third craft cms project but I’ve never had much experience with custom plug-ins.

What might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried composer commands for the same?

> composer update

For updating the composer

If it doesn't work try uninstalling the plugin then install it again with the following commands

> composer remove vendor/plugin-handle

For uninstalling the Plugin

> composer require vendor/plugin-handle

Install the plugin again then activate the same through CP

Hope this helps you in the same.